# cannot convert from method group to object porting WFP => UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, custom-controls, porting

For a project i've been working on i'm porting some custom controls from the WPF platform to UWP.
on the WPF side it is implemented as such:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLengthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaxLength", typeof(int), typeof(HexBox), new PropertyMetadata(MaxLength_PropertyChanged));
public int MaxLength
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MaxLengthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value); }
}
private static void MaxLength_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    HexBox hexControl = (HexBox)d;

    hexControl.txtValue.MaxLength = (int)e.NewValue;
}
```

with the `MaxLength_PropertyChanged` being used without arguments.
When i try to do the same in UWP i get greeted by the following message:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object'

I know this has to do with not passing the arguments, or calling them as a method with (). but in WPF this behavior was implicit.

anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLengthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "MaxLength",
  typeof(int),
  typeof(HexBox),
  new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(MaxLength_PropertyChanged))
);

private static void MaxLength_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    HexBox hexControl = d as HexBox;
    hexControl.txtValue.MaxLength = (int)e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: this works, thanks a bunch, turns out you need to be a lot more verbose in UWP.